# What is "cute" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

ReVo says *beleta*, but I've never liked to use *-et* in compliments. It sounds kind of like "not good enough to be beautiful".

*Dolĉa* is an option. It corresponds to the German "süß". But can it be used for sweet appearance, or only for sweet taste?

Another one I've seen is *ĉarma*. Does this word have anything to do with "charming"? Or is it closer to "cute"?

Answer (score 7):

*Ĉarma* certainly is the best choice. *Dolĉa* also works. Yes, *ĉarma* is related to charming, but it can be used with babies too.

A note on *linda*, which was suggested. I was not familiar with this word and it is rare in the Tekstaro - four references - two of them from the same work, and one of those being a gloss (footnote) of the other for readers (like me) who would otherwise have no idea what the author was trying to say. Wells has this word marked as "literary" i.e. not suitable for everyday Esperanto.

Answer (score 2):

Mi iam trovis en (sufiĉe respektata) vortaro la vorton *minjona*, sed efektive neniu esperantisto konis ĝin kiel esperantan vorton.

Do, ĉarma kaj dolĉa bonas.

Comment: Interese! Pensigas min pri la filmo "Minions". Tiuj karakteroj ja estas tre dolcxaj kaj cxarmaj.

Answer (score 1):

According to ReVo, **beleta** means a little bit beautiful.

**dolĉa** and **ĉarma** can both be used to describe someone's face. Therefore both are suitable. However, **ĉarma** seems more appropriate based on my understanding of the ReVo definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't they use the "affectionate" suffixes, hence *belonja* and *beloĉja*?

Comment: Nepre ne. -ĉj- kaj -nj- aperas nur post propra nomo aŭ nomo de parenceco: Manjo, Paŭĉjo, franjo, avĉjo...

Answer (score 0):

Laŭ mi la vorto *linda* plej proksimas al la angla *cute*.

Comment: Cxu linda estas vorto?

Comment: According to JC Wells' dictionary, _lind/-a_ means 'pretty', in literary usage.

Comment: Mi scias, ke Wells diras tion. Sed PIV diras, ke „linda” estas *alloge plaĉaspekta*, kio laŭ mi pli proksimas al „cute”.